# Using pandas to spilt a data column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an excel with a column called Event and Record.
I want to use pandas or any Python library or regular code to split the Event into Mens and Womens so I can plot a graph using matplotlib to compare the timing between men and women.
How can I go about cleaning the data?

[image: Meis 100m]

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
men = df[df['Event'].str.split(' ').str[0].eq('Mens')]
women = df.drop(men.index)
```